# Geometric Calculations for Group of Pixels

Tags: geometry, arcgis-pro, pixel

[image]I have group of pixels that I created by region group tool and I would like to measure the length and the width of each pixel group. I need max length and the width at half of the length of each group

My main goal is to extract the structure of each pixel group i.e whether it is linear or other pattern.

Would you recommend any tool for that?

Comment: How do you want length and width to be measured? Max length? Width at half the length of the Group? Mean width perpendicular to length axis?

Comment: I need max length and the width at half of the length of each group

Comment: Do you have advanced license?

Comment: yes i have advanced licence